# Android create clickable email link programmatically

Tags: android

I want to create an email link in an Android app.
If I do it this way:

```
<TextView
    android:text="xxxx@yyyy.zz"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:autoLink="email"/>
```

Then it works as it should.

I do, however, want to do it in code. The following example is a new Android project in Android Studio with a basic activity. I have added the marked code and added the id "mytest" to the auto-generated layout.

```
package com.example.bjursus.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.util.Linkify;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Added code - start
        getIntent().setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        ConstraintLayout clo = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.mytest);
        TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        tv.setText("zxxx@yyyy.zz");
        Linkify.addLinks(tv, Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES);
        tv.setLinksClickable(true);
        clo.addView(tv);
        // Added code - end

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This will give me the email link, but when I click it I get this exception:

AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The code you gave here will not compile since there is no class.

Comment: I have put the complete code

Comment: Please read the link I provided above.

Comment: I have read it and I would say the code I have supplied is a minimal, complete and verifiable example

Comment: From what I can tell, your question has nothing to do with `FloatingActionButton`, `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, nor `onOptionsItemSelected()`. So your code is far from **minimal**. I understand that these are generated when you create a new activity in Android Studio. As far as this question is concerned, they are just noise.

Comment: In addition, the XML snippet you provide is not **complete**. For one thing, it does not contain a `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: The above describes the minimal amount of work to reproduce the error. I do not see any reason why I should supply the complete XML of what is actually working, no need to reproduce that. Anyway, I considered this a simple, and easily reproducible problem, but apparently I was wrong.

Comment: It isn't reproducible when you provide partial code files. If I copy and paste what you have provided into Android Studio, I will get several compiler errors. It isn't minimal when you provide extra code that has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: You can continue wasting time by arguing. Or you can increase the chances of getting some help with your code by providing an actual [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this to the code

```
getIntent().setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

This will tell your activity it is okay to start a new task.

Comment: Does not solve the problem. My expanded example above does still generate the same error